# Informix 12.10 Find Percentage Completion Of Currently Running Query

Tags: informix, administration

How to check percentage of job completed for long query?

I found this query for SQL Server:

```
 SELECT 
     percent_complete,
     der.estimated_completion_time / 1000 "estimated_completion_time_in_seconds",
     *
 FROM
     sys.dm_exec_sessions des
 INNER JOIN 
     sys.dm_exec_requests der ON des.session_id = der.session_id
                              AND des.status = 'running'
```

Is there a similar one for Informix?

Can anybody help?

Comment: I don't think that information is available in Informix.  If it is available, it will be accessible via the SMI interface, which means via some (pseudo-)table in the sysmaster database.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : T_H_A_N_K_S Jonathan.

Comment: @marc_s T_H_A_N_K_S for Edit